# How to create a graphics like presented on the mathematica website as part of the latest features of Mathematica 11

Tags: graphics, charts

I was browsing through the new features of *Mathematica* 11 and found this picture on the website:

[image: distributions]

I'm trying to replicate this graphic (except for the logo in the middle of course) by means of the `SectorChart` function, but it seems very difficult to make it work. I got as far as this (only choosing a few sectors for demonstration purposes):

```
  size1 = 20; size2 = 8;
secDat = Table[{1, 1}, {x, 1, size2}, {y, 1, size1}];
SectorChart[secDat, ChartLayout -> "Grouped", 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", SectorOrigin -> {Automatic, 10}, 
 ChartLabels -> 
  Placed[Table["Label" <> ToString@x, {x, 1, size1}], "RadialInside", 
   Rotate[#, 90 Degree] &], 
 ChartLegends -> 
  Placed[Table["Legend" <> ToString@x, {x, 1, size2}], Below]]
```

Can someones help me with

1. aligning the labels such that they are in line with the grid lines like shown in the graphic. I tried to use the Rotate function but it rotates all labels
2. only showing the labels in the inner most layer
3. finding a way to automatically color only specific sections and not others like it is shown in the graphic

Any help appreciated!

Comment: See `SectorChart`.

Comment: [Searke says](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31623863#31623863): "What makes you so sure it was written 100% in Wolfram Language Code? Things like this tend to go thru design and are edited to fit in more with the style of the webpage."

Comment: Thanks all, I guess I just assumed it was made with Mathematica :). Sector Chart seems a possible way, but also looks quite different as in the picture. Any ideas how to start creating a chart like that with SectorChart?

Comment: @holistic the idea how to start it is clear, go to documentation and try it.

Comment: Yes, I tried to browse through the documentation of SectorChart, but still not sure how to even start getting that text in the middle while the grid is on the outside.

Comment: You could start with `ChartLabels -> 
 Placed[Automatic, "RadialInside",Rotate[#,somefunction]&], SectorOrigin -> {Automatic, 4}` in Sector chart

Comment: Thanks, that helped, but still a long way to go ;)

Comment: Does the solution have to use `SectorChart`?

Comment: @JEM_Mosig: If there is an easier way to create such a graph automatically, then I guess not :). But it seems the graphic was created with the SectorChart function

Comment: It could also just be a [`PieChart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PieChart.html.en) with opactities set and the logo / dashed lines added on top.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use `Graphics` and built it up yourself. One way to start may be:

```
Options[versionChart] = {
  LabelStyle -> Directive[White, Medium],
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Thick, Gray],
  ImageSize -> Large,
  ColorFunction -> ColorData[92],
  "CoreSize" -> 20
};

versionChart[data_,OptionsPattern[]] := With[{
    layers = Union@Flatten[Last/@data],
    elementCount = Length@DeleteDuplicates@Flatten[First/@data],
    innerDiskSize = OptionValue["CoreSize"]
  },
  Graphics[{
      (* draw inner part (except labels) *)
      Darker@Red,Disk[{0,0},innerDiskSize],
      (* generate sectors *)
      (* first, Table over all layers *)
      Table[
        (* for each layer, check which elements are active on this layer *)
        With[{elems=Flatten@Position[data,{_, _?(MemberQ[#,layer]&)}]},
          (* Table through all active elements *)
          Table[{
            (* set the sector color *)
            OptionValue[ColorFunction][layer],
            (* draw the sector *)
            Annulus[{0,0}, layer + innerDiskSize + {0,1}, {e-1/2, e + 1-1/2} 2 \[Pi] / elementCount],
            (* draw labels *)
            With[{angle=(e+1/2-1/2)2\[Pi]/elementCount},
              (* avoid upside-down labels *)
              If[\[Pi]/2<angle<3\[Pi]/2,
                Rotate[Text[Style[data[[e,1]], OptionValue[LabelStyle]],{-(innerDiskSize-1/2),0},{-1,0}],angle+\[Pi],{0,0}],
                Rotate[Text[Style[data[[e,1]], OptionValue[LabelStyle]],{(innerDiskSize-1/2),0},{1,0}], angle, {0,0}]
              ]
            ]
          }, {e,elems}]
        ]~Join~Table[
          (* draw intersection lines *)
          {OptionValue[GridLinesStyle], Line[Outer[Times,(innerDiskSize + layer + {0.2,0.8}), AngleVector[2\[Pi] (n-1/2)/elementCount]]]},
          {n, elementCount}
        ]~Join~{
          (* draw MMA polygon *)
          White,
          Polygon@(Join[#,{First[#]}]&)@Riffle[
            CirclePoints[{0.5 innerDiskSize,0},5],
            CirclePoints[{0.3 innerDiskSize,30 Degree},5]
          ]
        },
        {layer,layers}
      ]
    }, 
    ImageSize -> OptionValue[ImageSize]
  ]
]
```

Careful: this code is not super-robust, i.e. I do not check if the user gave good arguments and options. You may want to add this yourself, but for this post I think it is best if my code remains "clutter-free".

`versionChart` expects a `List` as argument, which shall be of the form `{{label1, {layerlist1}}, {label2, {layerlist2}}, ...}`, where the `layerlist`s are integers (incl. 0), and signify on which layers this data should have a sector. For example

```
versionChart[{
  {"uniform", {0, 4}},
  {"beta", {1, 3}},
  {"gamma", {0, 2}},
  {"delta", {3, 5}}
}]
```

gives

[image: simple example output]

and

```
versionChart[{#, RandomChoice[Range[0, 5], 3]} & /@ Names["*Distribution"],
 LabelStyle -> 
   Directive[
     LightRed, 
     FontSize -> Scaled[0.01], 
     FontFamily -> "Comic Sans"
  ],
  "CoreSize" -> 50,
  ColorFunction -> ColorData[93],
  ImageSize -> 2000,
  GridLinesStyle -> Gray
]
```

gives

[image]

For export, you may want to use `Rasterize` with a high setting for `ImageResolution`, so the text does not get scrambled.

Comment: Interesting solution, thank you! Yes, it looks quite similar to graphics. Can you also add some grid lines?

Comment: @holistic I added grid lines. Do you also want the star in the inside to look like the one in your figure? Or is this irrelevant?

Comment: No, it's fine like that ;)...Awesome! Thank you!!

Comment: Wow! My enthusiasm, however, is tempered by [your font choice](http://files.explosm.net/comics/Dave/comicsans2.png).